# MKMapView - cant locate user location while AirPlane mode is on

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, mkmapviewdelegate

I'm developing with MKMapView class,
When running on the device (iPhone5) and with AirPlane mode ON , Wi-Fi ON,

and the property of MKMapView：`showsUserLocation`setting to `YES`，the delegate of MKMapView

`- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didFailToLocateUserWithError:(NSError *)error`

is called, returning an error

```
Turn off airplane mode or use Wi-Fi to show your location on the map
```

telling me to turn of AirPlane mode or Turn on Wi-Fi to get location on the map.
My Airplane mode is on, but my Wi-Fi is Enabled, why can't I locate my position？

Is it a bug of MKMapView，or something else？
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[The apple documentation says](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html)

> Determining Whether Location Services Are Available
>
> Every iOS-based
> device is capable of supporting location services in some form but
> there are still situations where location services may not be
> available:
>
> The user can disable location services in the Settings app.
>
> The user
> can deny location services for a specific app.
>
> The device might be in
> Airplane mode and unable to power up the necessary hardware. For these
> reasons, it is recommended that you always call the
> locationServicesEnabled class method of CLLocationManager before
> attempting to start either the standard or significant-change location
> services. (In iOS 3.x and earlier, check the value of the
> locationServicesEnabled property instead.) If this class method
> returns YES, you can start location services as planned. If it returns
> NO and you attempt to start location services anyway, the system
> prompts the user to confirm whether location services should be
> reenabled. Given that location services are very likely to be disabled
> on purpose, the user might not welcome this prompt.

Nope not a bug it is said explicitly in the docs how to do it

Answer (score 0):

I believe that when the airplane mode is switched on it turns off all the possible ways to track your position, wi-fi included.

You can try it with your device by switching the airplane mode on while connected to the internet via wi-fi and accessing any webpage via safari.

Comment: I have the same thinking at the beginning,
but the built-in map in iPhone, or Google Maps, or other apps that requires location service works fine...

Comment: It probably caches your position from time to time. I don't think that's a bug: if you are switching off all the tracking possibilities, how would you be able to find the device's position?

Comment: but I've tried many times on different devices,
Turn on Airplane mode, then turn on Wi-Fi, Connect to Wi-Fi.
and Enable location service, open Google Map or Apple map start locate my position, it works everytime...

Comment: Could you try it for me on your phone?

Comment: I don't have any wifi available to try. I would say that if what you are sayng is accurate, the error message probably is not the desired one and there is in fact some kind of bug.

Comment: In addition, you could re-formulate your test by switching the airplane and wifi on, change your location and test with google maps' app.

Comment: Tried moving my location, the result comes same, it's not cache.

Comment: http://goo.gl/dTkVV this thread is having the same question...
but seemed not solved